# Is it safe to save persistent data as txt file for CoreData?

Tags: ios, core-data

My iOS app uses CoreData and some tables need to be filled with default values every first time the app is opened since CoreData device-dependent.

So I am using `NSUserDefaults` to check whether it is first time open. If it is first time, I fill tables (on CoreData) with the values which I have already created and formatted lines from the txt file by reading line by line and separating in a way.

And my question is, is it safe and fastest way to use txt file for such operation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A better option would be to keep a "canned" sqlite file in your app bundle and check for the existence of the SQLite file in your documents directory.  If the file does not exist, copy the canned data from the app bundle to your documents directory.

That will skip the entire parsing logic and will allow your application to launch faster.

Comment: Do I still need to check the existence of the SQLite file since no data added or removed during runtime (user can never change items on CoreData) instead of directly copying my default SQLite file every first time app is launched?

Comment: If the data is **never** changed then leave it in the AppBundle.  That also allows you to easily update the data on subsequent releases.

Comment: So the answer of my question is no, right? Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Marcus' approach is also what I would recommend. But you can still keep using your parsing code during development in order to have a convenient way to create the seed SQLite file. When you ship your app, package the newest seed store as a bundle resource and disable / delete your parsing code.

Comment: Parsing code should be part of the build process so that the seed data is always fresh.