# CoreData set standart data

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I've created an app which uses a UITableView. The data which is in the UITableView is saved into a database (I'm using CoreData). My question is, if it's possible to set standard data into the database/UITableView, which is shown after the first launch of the app?

Language: Swift; iOS: 7.0

Comment: There are several tutorials about this (there is also an SO answered by Marcus Zara that answers this too). Essentially you can store your data in the build version and then export the SQL DB and then bundle the SQL file into your app and load at first run. One sec...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27129262/is-it-safe-to-save-persistent-data-as-txt-file-for-coredata/27131798#27131798